# Ordinal equations using Cantor's normal form

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Find all possible ordinals $\alpha,\beta$ satisfying the equations:

1. $\alpha+\beta=\omega$
2. $\alpha+\beta=\omega^2+1$

For 1), discarding the trivial cases $\alpha=0$ or $\beta=0$, we have that $\omega^{\beta}\neq \omega$ for all $\beta\neq 1$, and $\omega\cdot k\neq\omega$ for all $k\neq 1$ (I guess these are obvious statements?) Also, $\omega+n\neq\omega$ (for $n>0$) and $n+\omega=\omega$ (for $n\geq 0$). Therefore, the only possibilities (taking into account the normal form of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $\alpha=n\in\omega$ and $\beta=\omega$, or $\alpha=\omega$ and $\beta=0$. I think these are all the solutions, since ordinals can't cancel each other to $0$, but I do not know if this answer is completely justified.

For 2) I did the same. Discarding $\alpha=0$ or $\beta=0$:
If $\alpha=n\in\omega$, then necessarily $\beta=\omega^2+1$, otherwise the equation is not satisfied.
If $\alpha$ is infinite, then necessarily $\alpha=\omega^2$, otherwise other powers of $\omega$ would appear, and $\beta$ cannot cancel them out. Then $\beta=1$, otherwise the equation is not satisfied.

Is this enough?

Comment: I do not see why $\alpha$ infinite gives $\alpha=\omega^2$. See what happens with $\alpha=2\cdot\omega$, $\beta=\omega^2+1$.

Comment: You’re right, then the equation is satisfied. How could I proceed, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recalling that ordinal addition is not commutative, such that $\alpha$ is "absorbed/annihilated" by $\beta > \alpha$ whenever $\beta \ge \omega$, i.e. $\alpha + \beta = \beta$ in that case $-$ it is due to the fact that the addition is interpreted as iterations of the successor function, with limit ordinals treated as unavoidable steps.

In consequence, the first equation $\alpha + \beta = \omega$ admits the following solutions
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
   \alpha = \omega \\
   \beta = 0
\end{array}
\right.
\quad\&\quad
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
   \alpha = n \\
   \beta = \omega
\end{array}
\right.
\quad\mathrm{with}\,
n \in \mathbb{N},
$$
while the second equation $\alpha + \beta = \omega^2 + 1$ leads to
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
   \alpha = \omega^2 + 1 \\
   \beta = 0
\end{array}
\right.
,\quad
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
   \alpha = \omega^2 \\
   \beta = 1
\end{array}
\right.
\quad\&\quad
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
   \alpha = \omega \cdot n + m \\
   \beta = \omega^2 + 1
\end{array}
\right.
\quad\mathrm{with}\,
n,m \in \mathbb{N}.
$$